# Setting up android widget icon in widget drawer - imagePreview issue?

Tags: android, image, widget

I am having problem with getting imagePreview to work. 
Thing is that in a widget drawer I cant see the image that I set as a preview one, but on click and hold(to get the widget to homescreen) I get the preview of image that I want.

This is my **widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="216dp"
android:minHeight="288dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:previewImage="@drawable/other_fun">
</appwidget-provider>
```

AndroidManifest file, widget_layout and widget.java should not have anything to do with this so I wont post them.
Any clue what could be causing this issue? I tried on several test phones, no luck so far..

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the DrawerView widget you won't see the Drawer in the preview in Android Studio. You will need to run your app on an emulator or device and then swipe on the side of the screen where the Drawer is placed (most likely left side by default).

Here is how I implemented the DrawerView in this [Sample Code](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Hacking_Environment) from Google's [design library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). The [CheeseSquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) example also implements the DrawerView nicely.

[image]